# Loopback4 MongoParseError: URI malformed

Tags: loopback, loopback4

There is no exception when I am trying without the Username and Password but I got error while giving value for user and password.

[The exception I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmSYI.png)

{
  "name": "Mongo",
  "connector": "mongodb",
  "url": "",
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 27017,
  "user": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "otc",
  "useNewUrlParser": true
}

Answer (score 2):

Actually the issue was the password I used, I used special characters (eg. '%') in my password so while parsing the URL the [URL parser Package used in loopback-mongo-connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) threw this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The URL option overrides all the other options, so If you send a string with no characters it will override anyway. So the alternatives are just using the URL or delete it and then try again.

Comment: Yeah, I know that and tried them... But that was not the issue I have posted an answer myself. I really appreciate the your response brother.

Thanks.